# How can I enable use of math in my html web page

Tags: php, javascript, html, latex, embed

I have a blog where people can post their comments. My problem is that I need to enable people to be able to use math formulas using latex syntax. I cannot make any changes to the server. I can only embed a script in my HTML page.
Kindly help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [jsMath](http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsMath/) to solve this problem.  It is all client side javascript, but you must reference the jsMath library to use its functions.

Comment: There's also MathJax, which seems to be shaping up as the successor to jsMath.

Comment: I can't install in the server.

Comment: You can link to it from any accessible location.  The library doesn't necessarily need to be on the same server.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/). Sample Blogger post: [MathJax testing](http://nonnewtonian.blogspot.com/2010/06/mathjax-testing.html)

Just add the following script:

```
<script src="http://www.mathjax.org/MathJax/MathJax.js">
  //
  //  This script call is what gets MathJax loaded and running
  //
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    // Only needed if to do more configuration within the page
    delayStartupUntil: "onload",
    // input is TeX and output is HTML-CSS 
    jax: ["input/MathML", "input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],    format
    // use the tex2jax preprocessor
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],              
    tex2jax: {
      // uncomment to use $...$ for inline math
      inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']],
      // set to 1 to allow \$ to produce a dollar sign 
      processEscapes: 1                      
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the [LaTeX 4 Web](http://eric.chopin.pagesperso-orange.fr/latex/latex4web.htm) library, which converts LaTeX code into HTML.

Answer (score 0):

you could use this script i guess:
http://eric.chopin.pagesperso-orange.fr/latex/latex4web.htm

Answer (score 0):

I searched for "javascript latex" and found:

- http://code.google.com/p/jstexrender/
- http://eric.chopin.pagesperso-orange.fr/latex/latex4web.htm
- http://www.codecogs.com/latex/install.php

I'd suggest trying one of these, or finding another.